# FROM_UNIXTIME and performance

Tags: mysql

Does FROM_UNIXTIME heavily affect the performance of a query like this:

```
        (
            (calltasks.task_dueDate = '".$date."') # Tasks of this date
            OR 
            (calltasks.task_dueDate < '".$date."' AND calltasks.task_status = 'scheduled') # Tasks still available on this date
            OR 
            (FROM_UNIXTIME(calltasks.task_executionTime, '%Y-%m-%d') = '".$date."') # Tasks finished this date
        )
```

Or I should be fine with it ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than converting your UNIX time to a formatted string, then comparing those (as you currently are), you would be better to use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to convert your `$date` variable to a UNIX time and then compare integers (checking the difference is no more than 24 hours).  Integer comparison will always be faster than string comparison:

```
(calltasks.task_executionTime - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$date')) BETWEEN 0 AND 86400
```

Alternatively, you may find that you already have the UNIX timestamp value of `$date` somewhere readily available in the language from which you are invoking this query: PHP, for example, stores dates as UNIX timestamps.

Note that you should be *absolutely certain* that `$date` cannot be manipulated to contain SQL if you are inserting it into your query in this fashion; if there is any doubt, you should use a prepared statement: if you don't know why, or what they are, read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Very useful answer, yet using UNIX_TIMESTAMP($date) will not give the accurate timestamp I need to compare the `task_execution` to, since date is Y-m-d in case you didn't notice.

Comment: ammm, I am not sure If you got me. $date = '2012-08-08' converting it to Unix format = "1344373200". The value stored in the database for `task_execution` contains the date and the time, so comparing the two this way is absolutely meaningless. Thanks

Comment: the data type of the `task_executionTime` column is INT

Comment: You can take advantage of the fact that "unix time" is expressed in seconds since the epoch and that the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` of your `$date` is the beginning of the day, as shown in the revised answer above.